# HttpRequest to SAP encoding $ and space caracters

Tags: apex, httprequest, encoding

I have a wierd problem:
I'm calling SAP from salesforce apex and I have trouble with one of my request.

This one is working.

> ```
>     request.setEndpoint(authentification_details.Webservice_enpoint__c+'/v1/product/ProductMasterSet(product=\''+productCode+ '\')?$format=json');
> ```

But the **next** one is not working

> request.setEndpoint(authentification_details.Webservice_enpoint__c+'/v1/product/ProductsSet?$filter=Productdescription eq \'*XXXXXX*\' and Language eq \'EN\'');

(XXXX is just a product code). I got a 400 code and the call never reach the SAP side.
I played around a bit and think i figured out that the '$' sign is possibly responsible for the error, because when i test in **postman** this is **working**.

**EDIT**: it was the spaces responsible for the errors (see answer below)

I did try encoding the $ sign using exa (%24) and unicode ($) Exa is not reaching SAP either but unicode is but is not interpreted correctly on SAP Side.

Does anyone has had this problem before? is there a way to force the encoding of my request so it's like postman?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I had to guess, the issue is likely not the dollar sign, but the query syntax in the URL since it has spaces. You may want to try encoding the spaces `%20` or using `+` signs instead since spaces in URLs can be problematic. It could also be the single quotes (Apex has to handle the string with escaped characters _first_ before it's ferried off to the HTTP service which can then re-encode) but you already have a working example with single quotes.

Comment: You can try sending the query string syntax to [Postman's Echo API](https://learning.postman.com/docs/developer/echo-api/) via Apex to see how the request gets encoded/changed.

Comment: @nbrown FWIW my first guess was the quotes too but they seem to be ok!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$` doesn't seem to cause any issues in a quick test I just performed. I created an endpoint at beeceptor.com, added a remote site setting and then ran this code via execute anonymous in my scratch org:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
String productCode = 'bob1234';
req.setEndpoint('https://quotes.free.beeceptor.com/v1/product/ProductMasterSet(product=\''+productCode+ '\')?$format=json');
req.setMethod('POST');
HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
```

[image: Screenshot from beeceptor.com showing the request has been received ok]

For the second request, the spaces appear to cause a 400 error. I also ran this code:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
String productCode = 'bob1234';
// req.setEndpoint('/v1/product/ProductMasterSet(product=\''+productCode+ '\')?$format=json');
String url = 'https://quotes.free.beeceptor.com/v1/product/ProductsSet?$filter=Productdescription eq \'XXXXXX\' and Language eq \'EN\'';
req.setEndpoint(url);
req.setMethod('POST');
HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
System.Debug(res);
```

Which gave me this in the log:

```
07:36:02.44 (238032455)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|System.HttpResponse[Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400]
```

And then modified it to encode the spaces:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
String productCode = 'bob1234';
String url = 'https://quotes.free.beeceptor.com/v1/product/ProductsSet?$filter=Productdescription eq \'XXXXXX\' and Language eq \'EN\'';
url = url.replaceAll(' ', '%20');
req.setEndpoint(url);
req.setMethod('POST');
HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
System.Debug(res);
```

And once again, this one got sent successfully. If SAP won't accept the URL with encoding then you might have some trickier issues to resolve!

[image: Screenshot from beeceptor.com showing the request with encoded spaces was receied ok]

Comment: I'm sorry, it's the second request that is not working not the first one I edited my question as it wasn't clear. Sorry about that. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @JulienSouchi I misread your question - my bad! Seems like the spaces are the issue, see my edits.

Comment: Thanks for the update, that was the spaces indeed. I'm getting to SAP now.
Thanks again